# React: cannot access mixin function inside getDefaultProps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mixins

I'm trying to access a function defined in a mixin from **getDefaultProps** but I get `undefined is not a function`. Basically I'm using `react-intl` and the default label of my column should be translated. Why I can't access functions defined in the mixin from within getDefaultProps?

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactIntl = require('react-intl');
var IntlMixin = ReactIntl.IntlMixin;

var Index = React.createClass({

  mixins: [IntlMixin],

  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return ({
      options: {
        attributes: [{name: 'name', label: this.getIntlMessage('Index.name'), index: 0}],
        view: "tiles"
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.options.attributes[0].label}</div>
  }
});

module.exports = Index;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can't be accessed because [`getDefaultProps`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getdefaultprops) is just called once and not in the context of an instance of the class you're creating. The `this` context isn't correct.

You'll need to move the retrieval into an instance function, like `render`.

You also should be aware that an array or object instance when returned in `getDefaultProps` is shared across all instances. I don't know how you're using it, but it could cause a problem depending on how you use the values.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I understand your points but I feel that it would be nice to be able to access the context from getDefaultProps. Perhaps I don't understand React well enough. :)

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, this answer is correct, you cannot access instance context from `getDefaultProps` because there is no instance. Per the docs: "Invoked once and cached when the class is created"

Comment: @AlanSouza - you can't access it ... it's not there as there's not a class. You'd need to use the functionality in a different way rather than relying on the mixin method.

Comment: This is a weird thing with createClass. In 0.13 with plain JS classes it's a property of the constructor, not the prototype, called defaultProps (along with getInitialState being removed and manually setting this.state in the constructor).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand- although in the end, it's still behaving as a static and non-instance method/value of the class in both cases. So, they did keep that consistent.